# CRM 2011 : workflow is postponed to 31/12/9999

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have created a workflow wait condition so that it will run 3 min after case creation as the screen shots describes but the problem that i found its status waiting and postponed till "31/12/9999" can anyone help me ?

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 2):

There is an error in your workflow. Instead of using "Process Execution Time" in the workflow, use "Time Out" option. Then your workflow will run correctly.

Follow these instructions:

1.If you want your workflow to wait for a specific amount of time you should use the wait step and configure the condition as: Process – timeout – equals – {Duration}. This will unload the workflow and resume execution after the specified time duration has passed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check whether the workflow was raised error during waiting. If yes, can you list the error.